# Github permanently delete a milestone option

Tags: github

I added a milestone option, but I no longer want to use it, but it still shows up in the dropdown. How can I permanently delete a milestone?

Comment: why did you not get the results detailed below from a search engine query?

Comment: I googled your question and got the answer linked by Mr Llama below.

Comment: not sure if you're using a different phrasing @Martin, but i don't get that link at all when I google it?

Comment: I searched for "how to delete a github milestone" and it came up as result number 3, the exact URL as described by MR Llama.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GitHub has a guide on how to [add, edit, or delete milestones](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-editing-milestones-for-issues-and-pull-requests/).